# Contact form HTML, Returning a "Success" text in the .html file

Tags: html, forms, contacts

i have this question and i can't find a solution. I'm pretty new in the programming. So..

my HTML file with the form is contact.html (straight html file)

The php code is in separated file. So, everythings work fine, but.. 
I want to have the return text for the "success" or "fail" in the  in my html file (let's say under the submit button). Is it possible if it's not php file with html code, but straight html. And can you tell me what should I do?

I hope you understand me.

Comment: yes, show your code and/or add a reproduce-able example in a jsfiddle

Comment: you can show dynamic messages in your html via jquery only, if you don't use jquery then your contact.html must be the contact.php file and then redirect back after submitting to other php and show the message

Comment: jQuery is **never** needed for anything. It is just a bunch of JavaScript written by other people. Anything it can do, you can do with different libraries or JavaScript you write entirely yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Straight HTML can't give different content conditionally.

You could get something that resembles what you describe by placing an `iframe` after the form and `target`ing it with the form. As solutions go, that's rather ugly.

You could use JavaScript to send the form data to the PHP file and then modify the DOM of the HTML document based on the response (Ajax), but that would be unnecessarily complex and violate the best practise of [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

The usual approach to this problem is to have a PHP file being the single entry point for all things relating to the form (it can keep parts of its logic or HTML in other files and `include()` them as needed) and have it decide, based on what input receives, if it should show:

- The plain form
- The form with error messages (and pre-populated with the user's incorrect submitted data)
- The thank-you

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Guess I'll see how to do this with Javascript, because i really want to keep .html file ... here's my answer code in the PHP file: 
$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
  window.location = 'contact_page.html';
 </script>

Comment: I guess i have to put in the javascript line some reference to a container in the .html file which sends this "Thank you" note to reveal it selfs in the container in the .html file